# Why can't I move this div and its content up?

Tags: css, html, layout, position

I am doing a practice because I recently started programming and I have come to areal block in my road, I am not kidding when I said I have been stuck in this part since morning, first with some troublesome images and now this.

Basically I need to move a div that has imgs and some text up so it stays just beneath the "Logo" but it won't budge! I tried to a lot of this but alas to no avail, I even checked it out on firebug and it appears as if the div containing the logo extends beyond what it should but I am positive I didn't mess it up like that.

Also I cannot use 
,styles in html or % for this.

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="imgs/logo.png" id="logo" />
    <img id="donate" />
        <div id="divMenu">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Our Programs </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Gallery </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Blog </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="bodyLogo">
    <img src="imgs/bg-featured.jpg"alt="" />
</div>
<div id="slogan">
    <p>As The Saying Goes.. </p>
    <p>You Don’t Know What You’ve Got </p>
    <p> ‘Till It’s Gone.</p>
    <h2>Plant A Tree.</h2>
    <h2> Grow A Tree.</h2>
    <h2><span id="tituloSpan">Save The Future.</span></h2>
</div>
```

Here is where it makes a invisible jump I cannot bridge!

```
<div id="divPictures"  class="opacity">

    <div class="left">
        <a href="#"><img src="imgs/help-out.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <p>"TEXT"</p>
        <div id="flecha">
            <img src="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right" >
        <a href="#"><img  src="imgs/what-we-do.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <p>"TEXT."</p>
        <div id="flecha">
            <img src="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
  body{
   width: 956px;
   font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
   background: url("../imgs/bg-header.jpg");
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
   text-decoration: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
   }


  #bodyLogo{
height: 396px;
position: relative;
margin: 18px 0 0 0;
}


#divPictures{
position: absolute;
width: 956px;
background:  url("../imgs/bg-body.jpg");
margin: 0 0 700px 0 ;
vertical-align: top;
}

.left{
width: 478px;
float:left;
font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
}

.right{
width: 478px;
float:right;
font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
}

 .left img, .right img{
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
 }

    #flecha{
background: url("../imgs/arrow-gray.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
width: 460px;
}
```

Thanks A LOT in advance.
Best Wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fixed height on your `#bodyLogo` which would make it extend past it's size. I don't know how large you have your images, but everything should snap right below it if you remove that height.

Comment: Thanks! I ended using position:absolute and deleting the height.